# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, bundler

I was trying to `bundle install`, but I keep on getting this error message.
[image]

My attempt was to update the version of ruby. However, this did not work. I also researched the compatible version of activerecord that corresponds to ruby version 2.2.5., but I was not able to find any.
I would truly appreciate it if you could resolve this error.

Here below is my gemfile for reference:

```
ruby '2.2.5'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.1'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', '~> 2.1'
gem 'webrick', '~> 1.7'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '~> 2.0'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 6.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2'
gem 'rake', '~> 13.0'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'sinatra-flash'

group :development do
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'fastri'
  gem 'rcodetools'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
end
```

Comment: According to [this table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) you would need to downgrade ActiveRecord to 5.2.x to still be able to run it with Ruby 2.2.x But I would argue that would be the wrong approach. Instead, you should focus on updating the ActiveRecord version because ActiveRecord (Ruby on Rails) 5.2 is unmaintained and reached end-of-life already. You will get more and more compatibility issue with such an old version of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Roger, thank you for your advice. I've tried reinstalling ruby with an updated version and it worked! Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling updated ruby version worked:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.6.3

bundle install
```